# Multiline Textbox from ssh remote text file

Tags: c#, linux, windows, winforms, ssh

I have a Windows form with a multiline textbox and a button. When the button is pressed, the program connects to my ssh server and prints the content of a text file (located on the server) into the textbox. 
The problem is that the textbox displays all the content of the file into a single line.
I cannot use

```
textbox.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine;
```

because I'm using the Linux  `cat` command to get the content of the file from the server. Can anyone help me??

Here is my code :

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new SshClient(host, port, user, pass))
        {
            //Start the connection
            client.Connect();
            var getmessage = client.RunCommand("cat messages/file.txt");
            textbox.Text = getmessage.Result;
            client.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you set `Multiline` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, the textbox is set to multiline, but now I used a rich textbox instead, and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n"). Hence "\n" should be converted to "\r\n" if you use a textbox.